# Prevent redirect to home page after add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, addtocart

I have an issue with the redirect after adding an item to the cart on my website (which someone else built and I now work on for my company). I turned off the automatic redirect to the cart in my Magento admin. However, when I add an item to my cart, the site now automatically goes to the home page - the product is still successfully added to the cart, but I want to remain on the current product page. From reading through other questions, it looks like the problem is that my site is customized so that the product pages are external (aka not internal to Magento). What php file do  need to customize, and what code do I need, in order to ensure that whenever the Add to Cart button is clicked on my site, the user stays on the current page?

Comment: Plz check all custom observer and controller related to add to cart. you will definitely find a way to resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

when you click on add to cart button checkout/cart/add action call
means in cart controller add action call so you customise your coding in add action.